# Area 51 public/private beta start timestamps are always identical

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, timestamps

On Area 51, the timestamps on the right-side of a proposal that show the starts of each phase show the exact same time for public and private beta starts. For example:

[image: Screenshot of Unix private beta start mouseover]

[image: Screenshot of Unix public beta start mouseover]

This happens even if the public beta hasn't started yet; the "in X days" text has the same mouseover timestamp as the private beta one:

[image: Screenshot of Android public beta start in two days]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. We were mistakenly showing the private beta start date in the tooltip for the public beta start date. It's fixed now.